# How to return the user ID in HTTP response after a user log in with DRF token authentification?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

My application has a `/login` endpoint where users can enter their login information, and after a user has been authenticated I would like to display a DRF view based on it's user ID as a parameter in the URL. What is the best way to do that ? Shall I need to include the user ID into the HTTP response and if so, how to do that ?

This is how the login view and serializer look like :

**view.py**

```
class LogInView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = LogInSerializer
```

**serializer.py**

```
class LogInSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        user_data = ManagerSerializer(user).data
        for key, value in user_data.items():
            if key != 'id':
                token[key] = value
        return token
```

The view I would like to display after the user login looks like this :

**view.py**

```
class AccountDetails(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
```

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('account/<pk>', AccountDetails.as_view()),

]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you need User ID? You can query it yourself from request.user. You just need to override the RetrieveApiView's get_object method:

```
class AccountDetails(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    
    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: Much simpler, thanks. It should be `self.request.user`